# Naive Question: How to convert max{t,0} to min{.. , ..}

Tags: optimization

Perhaps it is a very basic question, I want the following in $min$ form:

$\max\{A,B\}$

What is the equivalent $\min\{.,.\}$ formulation?

Thanks.

Comment: $\min\{A,B\}$? I think we need more details about your problem.

Comment: Here's a way to do it for the example in the title. I'll leave you to figure out how to do it in general. $-min\{-t, 0\}$ is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: So it should be $-min\{-t,0\}$? Thanks.

Comment: I want the formulation of Semi-variance in min form.
It is given as:

$\sigma_{-}(X)^2 = E[\max\{EX - X,0\}^2]$

I am looking for the above definition in $min$ form so something like (according to the above suggestion):

$\sigma_{-}(X)^2 = E[-\min\{-(EX - X),0\}^2]$

Comment: Next time, you might consider adding these highly relevant details to your original question! Asking the question in the body and not just in the title would be helpful to potential answerers as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will take care of that. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following relationship
$$
\inf_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\{x\} = -\sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\{-x\}
$$
where $\mathcal{X} = \{A,B\}$. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negative_of_Infimum_is_Supremum_of_Negatives) for details.

Answer (score 0):

max{A,B} = 1 - min{1 - A, 1- B}, I think